# Error with a function inside a Lapply() R

Tags: r, lapply

I'm having a very strange error in a script that used to work perfectly and I don't know what's the problem. I start creating a very long list with several data frames with the exact number of columns. The list is called lst. Then I want to do a summarise table with means and sd. Here is the script for that:

```
 w1 <- lapply(lst, function(i) t(cbind(Mean = colMeans(i[, c(6,7,8,9)], na.rm = TRUE), 
                                  Sds = colSds(as.matrix(i[, c(6,7,8,9)]), na.rm = TRUE),
                                  N = length(i[,2]),
                                  len.max=max(i[,6]))))
```

The number of the columns are correct. However when I run the script first I get the Debug location and when I stopped I get this error message:

```
Error in t(cbind(Mean = colMeans(i[, c(6, 7, 8, 9)], na.rm = TRUE), Sds = colSds(as.matrix(i[,  : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error in `[.data.frame`(i, , c(6, 7, 8, 9)) : undefined columns selected
```

I dont know whats wrong with the function. I try to search in the internet and I saw something about change as,matrix for data.matrix. However this does not make the trick.

Indeed I get the same problem for another function very similar:

```
a1 <- lapply(lst, function(i) t(cbind(l1 = NROW(which(i[,6]>1)),
                                  l1.05 = NROW(which(i[,6]<=1)) - NROW(which(i[,6]>0.5)),
                                  l05.03 = NROW(which(i[,6]>0.3)) - NROW(which(i[,6]<=0.5)),
                                  l03 = NROW(which(i[,6]<=0.3)))))
```

With the same outcome:

```
Error in t(cbind(l1 = NROW(which(i[, 6] > 1)), l1.05 = NROW(which(i[,  : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': Error in `[.data.frame`(i, , 6) : undefined columns selected
```

Can someone point me out what is the problem. Do you need some data? Thanks!

I'm working with the last RStudio and with the following packages: 
plyr, matrixStats,dplyr

Here is an example of the list:

```
> lst
[[1]]
  X Chr new     pos1     pos2 len     nsnp    n.ind   per.ind
1 1   1   1 12900000 13700000 0.9 284.7560 23.77778  7.952434
2 2   1   2 17000000 17300000 0.4 126.5582 16.00000  5.351171
3 3   1   3 21200000 21500000 0.4 126.5582 40.75000 13.628763
4 4   1   4 45300000 45700000 0.5 158.1978 23.20000  7.759197
5 5   1   5 45900000 46600000 0.8 253.1165 31.12500 10.409699

[[2]]
  X Chr new     pos1     pos2 len      nsnp    n.ind  per.ind
1 1   1   1 12900000 13700000 0.9 312.90267 24.44444 4.288499
2 2   1   2 21200000 21500000 0.4 139.06785 38.00000 6.666667
3 3   1   3 32600000 33000000 0.5 173.83482 28.40000 4.982456
4 4   1   4 35800000 36100000 0.4 139.06785 37.25000 6.535088
5 5   1   5 36300000 36300000 0.1  34.76696 22.00000 3.859649

[[3]]
  X Chr new     pos1     pos2 len     nsnp    n.ind  per.ind
1 1   1   1 35700000 36500000 0.9 287.4214 12.22222 11.42264
2 2   1   2 45900000 46600000 0.8 255.4857 12.50000 11.68224
3 3   1   3 49400000 50700000 1.4 447.1000 21.78571 20.36048
4 4   1   4 51000000 52000000 1.1 351.2929 16.00000 14.95327
5 5   1   5 52200000 53000000 0.9 287.4214 19.66667 18.38006

dput(lst[1:3])
list(structure(list(X = 1:5, Chr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), new = 1:5, 
pos1 = c(12900000, 1.7e+07, 21200000, 45300000, 45900000), 
pos2 = c(13700000, 17300000, 21500000, 45700000, 46600000
), len = c(0.9, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8), nsnp = c(284.756031128405, 
126.558236057069, 126.558236057069, 158.197795071336, 253.116472114137
), n.ind = c(23.7777777777778, 16, 40.75, 23.2, 31.125), 
per.ind = c(7.95243403939056, 5.35117056856187, 13.628762541806, 
7.75919732441472, 10.4096989966555)), .Names = c("X", "Chr", 
"new", "pos1", "pos2", "len", "nsnp", "n.ind", "per.ind"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(X = 1:5, Chr = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), new = 1:5, pos1 = c(12900000, 21200000, 32600000, 
35800000, 36300000), pos2 = c(13700000, 21500000, 3.3e+07, 36100000, 
36300000), len = c(0.9, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1), nsnp = c(312.90267141585, 
139.0678539626, 173.83481745325, 139.0678539626, 34.76696349065
), n.ind = c(24.4444444444444, 38, 28.4, 37.25, 22), per.ind = c(4.28849902534113, 
6.66666666666667, 4.98245614035088, 6.53508771929825, 3.85964912280702
)), .Names = c("X", "Chr", "new", "pos1", "pos2", "len", "nsnp", 
"n.ind", "per.ind"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame"), 
structure(list(X = 1:5, Chr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), new = 1:5, 
    pos1 = c(35700000, 45900000, 49400000, 5.1e+07, 52200000
    ), pos2 = c(36500000, 46600000, 50700000, 5.2e+07, 5.3e+07
    ), len = c(0.9, 0.8, 1.4, 1.1, 0.9), nsnp = c(287.421428571429, 
    255.485714285714, 447.1, 351.292857142857, 287.421428571429
    ), n.ind = c(12.2222222222222, 12.5, 21.7857142857143, 
    16, 19.6666666666667), per.ind = c(11.4226375908619, 
    11.6822429906542, 20.3604806408545, 14.9532710280374, 
    18.380062305296)), .Names = c("X", "Chr", "new", "pos1", 
"pos2", "len", "nsnp", "n.ind", "per.ind"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example for `lst`.  BTW, you may need to check if the number of columns are there in each of the `data.frame` in the `list`

Comment: Based on the updated dataset, I am not finding any error with the code

Comment: Done! And yes, the number of columns are correct.

Comment: If there is no error in the code, how I get that error message? What can I do?

Comment: I tried both the  functions with the updated `lst`, it is not giving any error.  I am using  `matrixStats_0.52.2`

Comment: Can u check the `class` of the columns and the `str(lst)`

Comment: Yes, I did, all numeric except X, Chr and New that are int... I don't know what to do, I still get the error... I really don't understand why you are not getting it.

Comment: Can you update with the dput of the `lst` containing only the 3 datsets that you showed

Comment: Sorry? dput  I don't know what's that...

Comment: Suppose you `dput(lst[1:3])` on the console, you will get an output.  Please copy and paste in your post.  It is to understand whether the structure of your data is the same as the one I used from copying the data you showed

Comment: Even the dput data is working fine for me.  I am using R 3.4.0

Comment: I'm using RStudio 1.0.143... F*** I don't know what to do. I tried all... I need to summarise the complete list that is huge.

Comment: Should I try in normal R?

Comment: Yes, Can you try it on a R console.  I use R 3.4.0.  Please check if your R version is upto date

Comment: Ok, I just tried in R 3.4.1. and I get now an error with the columns: Error in `[.data.frame`(i, , c(6, 7, 8, 9)) : undefined columns selected

Comment: No idea why it is having a problem with you as it is working fine for me

Comment: It's weird because If try to obtain results element by element I get the outcomes colMeans(lst[[1]][,c(6,7,8,9)]) or colSds(as.matrix(lst[[1]][,c(6,7,8,9)]), na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: That is weird for me

Comment: So, I imagine that the problem must be in function(i)... Should I change this?

Comment: You can check `lapply(lst, function(x) colMeans(x[, 6:9]))`

Comment: Same outcome: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , 6:9) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Can you try it on a fresh sesssion?  Or try creating a new data i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 4*5, replace = TRUE), 4, 5))); lapply(lst1, colMeans)`

Comment: SOLVED!!!!! The problem was that one of the elements of the list was not read it correctly since it was a .csv but with ";" not "," thanks a lot for your help. Thanks to you I was able to find where the problem suppose to be!

Comment: I didn't get it.  Can u elaborate

Comment: In order to build the list, I have to read and gather a lot of csv (more than 1000) One of them couldn't be read using read.csv but with read_delim...

Comment: Ok, one way to remove is `lst1 <- Filter(length, lst)` to remove that one